# Couldn't find add-on hobby-dev for PostgreSQL database on Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, add-on

I'm trying to push my application to Heroku using Django, however when I run `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev -a (appname)` it gives me this error:

`Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev".` !
I have also checked that the free version was changed from November 28th, 2022. Is there any other Database add-ons that is reliable so I can use to deploy my app on Heroku. Any suggestions?

Comment: I changed `heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev` to `heroku-postgresql:mini` and it worked as expected.  Thanks for the tip, @Myth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Heroku CLI to check which are the available add-ons by heroku:

```
heroku addons
```

There are some other databases which you can use for deploy on heroku like:

`Heroku Postgres:` There are paid service of heroku postgres available with plans, [pricing of heroku postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql#pricing).
There are some 3rd party add-ons which you can use in postgres too =>
`ElephantSQL`, `mLab`, `clearDB`

Answer (score 0):

According to [heroku's website](https://help.heroku.com/PG7U1DIF/what-happened-to-my-free-data-add-on-why-am-i-unable-to-find-free-plan-heroku-postgres-database-which-i-used-to-have-earlier-is-my-data-being-deleted-if-so-when-and-how), "The free plans for Heroku Postgres have being retired on November 28, 2022." So sadly, there is no hobby-dev (free) tier anymore.